# Mixed Content: The page at 'https://localhost:44387/Home/Index' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, http

I have been trying to make an AJAX request from localhost (which is onfigured for https) to a server that is over http. everytime i receive an error from the browser saying it has been blocked since there is some "mixed content" in the call.
How can i avoid such error? sometimes in the browser I can see the JSON response I need but it never makes it to the page due to the error.

Here is the code when i click on a button to request data:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var gallery = null;

$("#getSubscriptionWorkflows").click(function () {
    gallery = new Gallery($("#apiLocation").val().trim(), $("#apiKey").val().trim(), $("#apiSecret").val().trim());
    gallery.getSubscriptionWorkflows(function (workflows) {
        var listStr = "";
        var len = workflows.length;
        if (len === 0) {
            listStr = "There are no workflows in the subscription associated with the given api key";
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            listStr += "<li>" + workflows[i].metaInfo.name + " - " + workflows[i].id + "</li>";
        }
        $("#workflowList").html(listStr);
    }, function (response) {
        $("#workflowList").html(response.responseJSON && response.responseJSON.message || response.statusText);
    });
});
});
```

And here is the API code:

```
Gallery = function(apiLocation, apiKey, apiSecret) {
this.apiKey = apiKey;
this.apiSecret = apiSecret;
this.apiLocation = apiLocation;

this.getSubscriptionWorkflows = function (success, error){
    var type = "GET",
        url = this.apiLocation + "/workflows/subscription/",
        params = buildOauthParams(this.apiKey),
    //add any user parameters before generating the signature
        signature = generateSignature(type, url, params, this.apiSecret);
    $.extend(params, {oauth_signature: signature});
    $.ajax({
        type: type,
        url: url,
        data: params,
        success: success,
        error: error
    });
};
```

Comment: You can't make mixed content calls.

Comment: Did you happen then to know a way to make a visual studio project run on http and not https?